# Issue with Hibernate and missing entities

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

We have a Java application that uses Hibernate to map objects to an Oracle database, and while everything normally works fine, there's a particular case that is causing problems. First, a brief overview of the mapping:

**User** class, which is mapped to APP_USER, which is a table. It has a OneToMany mapping to OrgUser objects:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<OrgUser> orgUsers;
```

**OrgUser** class, which is mapped to ENTITY_USER, which is a table. It has a ManyToOne mapping to User objects and a ManyToOne mapping to Organization objects:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "APP_USER_FK", nullable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_FK", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "org")
    private Organization organization;
```

**Organization** class, which is mapped to ENTITY_VW, which is a view. It has a OneToMany mapping to OrgUser:

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "organization")
    private Set<OrgUser> orgUsers;
```

In normal use, that is all fine. However, Organizations can be removed from the ENTITY_VW view if they are no longer active. Which is usually also fine; the associated ENTITY_USER records just get ignored. The problem arises when trying to add a new ENTITY_USER record via a new OrgUser object:

OrgUser #1 (already exists)

- User: 1327
- Organization: ORG-00001

OrgUser #2 (already exists)

- User: 1327
- Organization: ORG-00002

OrgUser #3 (new)

- User: 1327
- Organization: ORG-00003

The code creates a new OrgUser object with User=1327 and Organization=ORG-00003, which is then saved via merge() in the DAO:

```
    public Object saveOrgObject(Object object) {
        return entityManager.merge(object);
    }
```

The issue, however, is that the merge() tries to touch all associated records, and because Organization ORG-00002 no longer exists, an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Organization with id ORG-00002
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:155) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1079) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1006) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:441) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:995) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:874) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2033) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3719) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1079) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1006) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:441) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) ~[spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy53.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at OrgUserDao.saveOrgObject(OrgUserDao.java:177) ~[classes/:na]
```

The question is, is there a way to set things up so this isn't an issue? In a worst case scenario we can manually delete the orphaned ENTITY_USER records from the database, but because entities can/will continue to be removed from ENTITY_VW, it would be an ongoing issue.

Comment: So basically you are saying that additional to your Hibernate application other session access the database directly and perform `delete`s there. Try to persuade them to make only *logical delete* by updating a status and *increase the `version`by 1*. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Short answer: We can't do that.

Longer answer: This isn't just a database for the Java application, it's for the entire business, and there are certain things we don't have direct control over. Both the Java app and the overall database are legacy systems and making such a change would require a significant overhaul to both.